# Entity Framework Core - assigning single disconnected entity to multiple instances of new related entity

Tags: c#, .net, database-design, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set-up correctly the following scenario:

```cs
public class Vendor
{
    [Key]
    public long VendorId { get; set; }

    public HashSet<PlantSpecific> PlantSpecificData { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```cs
[Owned]
public class PlantSpecific
{
    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public long VendorId { get; set; }
    //Since PlantSpecific is owned by Vendor I don't need navigation property

    [ForeignKey("PlantId")]
    public long PlantId { get; set; }
    public Plant Plant { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IncotermId")]
    public long? IncotermId { get; set; }
    public Incoterm Incoterm { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>(v =>
{
    v.OwnsMany(plnt => plnt.PlantSpecific, a =>
        {
            a.HasKey(x => new { x.VendorId, x.PlantId });
            a.HasIndex(i => i.IncotermId).IsUnique(false);
            a.HasIndex(i => i.PlantId).IsUnique(false);
            a.HasIndex(i => i.VendorId).IsUnique(false);
           
            a.HasOne(p => p.Plant).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            a.HasOne(p => p.Incoterm).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        });
});
```

So to sum up: I would like to enable multiple PlantSpecific data per one Vendor, with Plant as a required entity and unique for this specific Vendor. No limitations for Incoterm entity are considered.

The problem occurs when I try to add new Vendor doing the following steps:

1. Load all Plants and Incoterms `AsNoTracking` from database (please consider loading them not being tracked as a must)
2. Add `PlantSpecific` data to Vendor for each existing Plant and **assign the same existing Incoterm to all instances**
3. Update database:

```cs
VendorDbContext.AttachRange(vendor.PlantSpecificData
     .Select(x => x.Plant));

VendorDbContext.AttachRange(vendor.PlantSpecificData
     .Where(x => x.Incoterm != null)
     .Select(x => x.Incoterm));

VendorDbContext.Vendors.Add(vendor);
await VendorDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I attach all related entities to the context as they are disconnected, otherwise EF tries to insert them and throws error.

Unfortunately only last instance of `PlantSpecific` gets the right Incoterm and all remaining get `null`.

I tried to load them `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`, but it doesn't solve the problem. Neither does attaching Incoterm only once - then only the first instance of PlantSpecific gets it assigned properly.

**Edit:**

The whole process of creating `Vendor` is done via UI Components:

1. After a component is initialized, all available entities are fetched from db

```
HashSet<Plant> plants = new(await dbContext.Plants.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync())
HashSet<Incoterm> incoterms = new(await dbContext.Incoterms.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync())
Vendor vendor = new();
```

2. A user may add `PlantSpecific` data by selecting fetched plant (possibly multiple times per each plant available)

```
PlantSpecific plantData = new();
plantData.Plant = plant;
plantData.PlantId = plant.PlantId;
vendor.PlantSpecific.Add(plantData);
plants.Remove(plant); //selected plant gets removed from available plants
```

3. A user assigns fetched incoterm to previously added plantData (possible multiple times per each plantData perviously added)

```
plantData.Incoterm = incoterm;
plantData.IncotermId = incoterm.IncotermId;
```

4. vendor is passed to another function with different DbContext, all related entities get attached

```
VendorDbContext.AttachRange(vendor.PlantSpecificData
     .Select(x => x.Plant));

VendorDbContext.AttachRange(vendor.PlantSpecificData
     .Where(x => x.Incoterm != null)
     .Select(x => x.Incoterm));

VendorDbContext.Vendors.Add(vendor);
await VendorDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If the same `Incoterm` is added to all `PlantSpecific` data, only the last one have it assigned properly, all others have `null`.
However, if every `PlantSpecific` entity have different `Incoterm`, all works fine and is saved to the database properly.

Comment: Could you please include the code you use to add a new vendor?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question and added whole process in a nutshell how the vendor is created and added. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: `PlantSpecific` - `Incoterm` is defined as 1:1, but reading your description it should be 1:n.

Comment: Thank you, so this line in `modelBuilder`: `a.HasOne(p => p.Incoterm).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);` should be replaced with `a.HasOne(p => p.Incoterm).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);`, am I right?

Comment: Today I could finally apply and test these changes and indeed it was a problem... Thank you!